# Error about Python modules no module named: "Name of module"

Tags: python, module

well, my problem is that before rebooting my system, i saved all my current works, installed all the necessary packages i run the programs it worked perfectly well.

after rebooting my system, I tried again with all my packages still installed but this time it is putting me this error.

"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyttsx3'problems it is like that with all of my other Modules I already installed them and run my program, I'm stuck and can't understand what's happening.

here is a piece of my code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import speech_recognition as sr
import webbrowser
import pyttsx3 
import wikipedia
import wolfframalpha


# Speech engine initialisation
engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id) # 0 = male, 1 = female
activationWord = 'Computer'
```

i was expecting it to be good and run properly like before rebooting my laptop.

Any help? thank you.

Comment: did you check with `pip list` to see whether the package is already there?

Comment: Can you check if you've installed the packages in a virtual env?